# Publishing Nuget Packages using Gitlab CI

Tags: .net, gitlab, continuous-integration, nuget, gitlab-ci

I have followed this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools-how-to-create) on how to create a nuget tool package.

Now I want to deploy this package when I create tags in my Gitlab Pipeline:

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

variables:
  PACKAGE_SOURCE:
    value: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
    description: Specifies the Nuget package server URL.

image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0

build-job:
  stage: build
  script:
  - dotnet build -c Release
  artifacts:
    untracked: true

package-job:
  stage: build
  needs:
    - job: build-job
      artifacts: true
  script:
  - dotnet pack -c Release --no-build --output nupgk
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - nupgk

deploy-job:
  stage: deploy
  only:
  - tags
  needs:
    - job: package-job
      artifacts: true
  script:
  - echo "Pushing package to $PACKAGE_SOURCE"
  - dotnet nuget push nupgk/*.nupkg --api-key "$PACKAGE_SERVER_TOKEN" --source "$PACKAGE_SOURCE"
```

The build job and the packaging works fine and then in the deploy job (when i push a tag to the repository) i get the following message:

```bash
$ echo "Pushing package to $PACKAGE_SOURCE"
Pushing package to https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

$ dotnet nuget push nupgk/*.nupkg --api-key "$PACKAGE_SERVER_TOKEN" --source "$PACKAGE_SOURCE"
warn : No API Key was provided and no API Key could be found for 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package'. To save an API Key for a source use the 'setApiKey' command.
Pushing mypackage.myversion.nupkg to 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package'...
  PUT https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/
  Unauthorized https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/ 570ms
error: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (An API key must be provided in the 'X-NuGet-ApiKey' header to use this service).
```

I do not understand this behaviour, because when I run the exact same commands on my local machine (using the same docker image) i get the following output:

```bash
$ echo "Pushing package to $PACKAGE_SOURCE"
Pushing package to https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

$ dotnet nuget push nupgk/*.nupkg --api-key "$PACKAGE_SERVER_TOKEN" --source "$PACKAGE_SOURCE"
Pushing mypackage.myversion.nupkg to 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package'...
  PUT https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/
  Created https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/ 1090ms
Your package was pushed.
```

It also seems that dotnet nuget is totally ignoring my source argument, i also dont know why that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this seems to be an issue outside of the pipeline configuration. It turns out that Gitlab, by default, sets variables as protected (which i confused with masked). This means that the `PACKAGE_SERVER_TOKEN` variable was not available on the tag pipeline because the tag itself was not protected at the time of its creation.

Fix: I added a wildcard tag protection rule `v*` to create a protected tag and additionally modified the pipeline to only run if a ref is protected (to ensure the variable is set when the job is created)

```yaml
...
deploy-job:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    refs:
      - tags
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_REF_PROTECTED
...
```